# How can I navigate to the questions page with the "Interesting" questions filter option?

Tags: support, interesting-page

When I enter Stack Overflow, I find an "Interesting Questions" option:

[image]

but when I click the "Stack Overflow" button on the left sidebar, that option disappears:

[image]

How can I go back?

Comment: Clicking the SO logo (while logged in) will take you back to that.

Comment: Can you clarify what "stack overflow" button you mean? Clicking the logo takes you back to the main page (which has that), and I'm not sure what else you might be referring to.

Comment: "Stack Overflow" in the left menu takes you to /questions

Comment: @KevinB Oh right, I always forget that the left menu exists.

Comment: I wonder why would someone want that tab, the questions there are totally not "interesting". Looks like an attempt of someone to do something what google search does. Poor attempt.

Comment: @Sinatr I effectively wonder how a trivial JS question with 2 views and nothing else gets to be selected as "Interesting"

Comment: maybe interesting for JS developers? I guess...

Comment: the interesting tab is generated by a set of rules that take into account not only the posts score/tags/activity, but also *your* tags activity and in some cases rep. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/09/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Interesting" is a tab that solely exists on the site homepage for logged-in users: https://stackoverflow.com

Once you click on "Stack Overflow" on the left menu, you're taken to /questions, which doesn't include that tab.

In my humble opinion, the left menu of *all* other network sites are far more clear/useful than what SO currently has.

- Home
- Questions
- Tags
- Users

on SO, we get:

- Home (-> /)
- Public (not clickable)

  - Stack Overflow (-> /questions)

    - Tags
    - Users
    - Jobs
- Teams

Wouldn't this be much easier to understand for users who aren't using teams? Maybe even throw in a "Meta" link in there, it's not like we don't have the space.

- Home
- Questions
- Tags
- Users
- Jobs
- Teams

Comment: You forgot “Marketing Banners”. Oh wait, sorry, that’s “Home” now... The “interesting” tab was my most-used page, aside from the flag dashboard. I very much dislike that it’s now been made even more inconsistent and hard to get to.

Comment: I'm in a team and I don't see the tabs on the homepage :/